# custom install hook and rpmbuild

Tags: makefile, rpm, autotools, rpmbuild

I have a package that uses autotools for build/install/etc.  It is a Python module written in C++.  (This isn't important except to know that the python scripts I have to install aren't part of what's being built, i.e. they're not a `xxxxx_SOURCES` primary.)  This module is used solely for some "unit tests" for a driver that our team distributes in a HW solution.  For various reasons, I have need to "install" the python unit tests with the system.

Since these python scripts aren't part of the module, I'm managing the installation separately in the Makefile.  Here's what I have in my `Makefile.am`:

```
EXTRA_DIST = setupenv.sh bootstrap tests

dist-hook:
    rm -rf $$(find $(distdir)/tests -name \*.swp -o -name \*.pyc)


install-exec-hook:
    mkdir -p $(prefix)/unit_tests/unittest2
    for f in tests/*.py; do \
        cp $$f $(prefix)/unit_tests; \
    done

    for f in tests/unittest2/*.py; do \
        cp $$f $(prefix)/unit_tests/unittest2; \
    done

uninstall-hook:
    rm -r $(prefix)/unit_tests
```

This works just fine except during `rpmbuild` for the module.  The `install-exec-hook` rule isn't written correctly to make the directory where the rpm process redirects it.  That is, when `mkdir - $(prefix)/...` is executed, the script literally tries to make the dir: **/opt/oursw/...**.  How should this rule be rewritten so that rpmbuild puts them in the same place as the installation for the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add `$(DESTDIR)` as a prefix to all those directories. That's [standard for autotools installs](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/DESTDIR.html).

As an aside, you also might want to look at the `_SCRIPTS` suffix, which allows "`make install`" to copy your scripts in for you the "official" way, removing the need for this hack in the first place.

Comment: Thank you.  In the end I had done just this, but as an experiment.  The process I'm leveraging, pre-dating my presence on this team, sets DESTDIR when calling `make install`.  I really didn't want to answer my own question and I wasn't sure I was doing this the correct way.